# React: Где хранить картинки и как настроить их хранение

Tags: reactjs

Добрый день.

Разрабатываю проект на React. Храню картинки в корне проекта. В css стилях прописываю пути для них примерно так '../../textures/pic.jpg' т.е. выхожу в корень за ними. Но в компонентах прописав так:

```
<img src="../../textures/pix/logo.png"/>
```

Картинка не появляется.

Как в React приложениях организовывать хранение картинок?

Наверяка их в Dist надо преносить, что бы при деплое они рядом с index.html лежали?

Как это в webpack прописать для build и start?

И какие пути до картинок будут после этого в компанентах и css?

Спасибо.

Comment: Если вы хотите добратся из компоненты к картинке, учитивали что путь должен быть исходя из того что исполняемый текущий скрипт у вас /dist/js/main.js ? Для примера

Comment: А он точно там? При npm run start не создается dist.

Comment: у вас в package.json прописан sripts с запуском вебпака?)

Comment: "start": "npm-run-all --parallel open:src lint:watch"

Comment: смотрите в конфиге вебпака какой у вас в аутпуте path.resolve

Comment: Такой: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index')

Comment: Дак как мне достучаться до до картинок (каким путем)?

Comment: import backtostart from 'src/assets/backtostart.png';<img src={share} width="30" height="30"/>